# How to check request conditionally in ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have got below ASP html

```
<div id="divCheckAll">
    <div class="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkOperationalUpdate" name="chkOperationalUpdate" value="1" />
        Operational Update
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkLounges" name="chkLounges" value="1" />
        Lounges
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkLocations" name="chkLocations" value="1" />
        Locations
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkChauffeurdrive" name="chkChauffeurdrive" value="1" />
        Chauffeurdrive
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="selectall">
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkFleet" name="chkFleet" value="1" />
        Fleet
    </div>
</div>
```

Now on my button click and form action, I am calling another ASP page which is taking above html values as request. I want to check if any of the above checkbox is not checked then it would return some message back, something like below:

```
If Request("chkOperationalUpdate")="" or Request("chkLounges")="" or Request("chkLocations")="" or Request("chkChauffeurdrive")="" or Request("chkFleet")="" Then    
    Response.Write "<font color='red'>Please select at least one items to be published</font>"
    Response.End
End If
```

Above condition works perfectly for checking one request, however I want if user has selected any of the checkboxes then it should not return any message, it should return message only if user missed to select any of the checkboxes.

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `or` with `and`, this way it will display message of selecting atleast one `CheckBox` if user hasn't selected..

```
'none of the checkbox is selected
If Request("chkOperationalUpdate")="" and Request("chkLounges")="" and Request("chkLocations")="" and Request("chkChauffeurdrive")="" and Request("chkFleet")="" Then    
    Response.Write "<font color='red'>Please select at least one items to be published</font>"
    Response.End
Else
    'User has selected atleast one checkbox
End If
```

Comment: Sometime we get confused, this time it was my turn ;)..thanks